# Java driver for apache cassandra maven fail to build

Tags: cassandra, datastax-enterprise, datastax-java-driver

I am trying to use Cassandra Java driver.
I am getting below error when using Maven build.

Multiple annotations found at this line:

```
- ArtifactTransferException: Failure to transfer org.apache.cassandra:cassandra-thrift:jar:1.2.3 from repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was 
             cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could 
             not transfer artifact org.apache.cassandra:cassandra-thrift:jar:1.2.3 from/to central (h://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): No response received after 
             60000
            - ArtifactTransferException: Failure to transfer com.github.stephenc.high-scale-lib:high-scale-lib:jar:1.1.2 from h://repo.maven.apache.org/
             maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced. Original 
             error: Could not transfer artifact com.github.stephenc.high-scale-lib:high-scale-lib:jar:1.1.2 from/to central (h://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): No 
             response received after 60000
            - ArtifactTransferException: Failure to transfer org.mortbay.jetty:jetty:jar:6.1.22 from h://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the 
             local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer 
             artifact org.mortbay.jetty:jetty:jar:6.1.22 from/to central (h://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): No response received after 60000
            - ArtifactTransferException: Failure to transfer io.netty:netty:jar:3.6.3.Final from h://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local 
             repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer artifact 
             io.netty:netty:jar:3.6.3.Final from/to central (h://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): No response received after 60000
            - ArtifactTransferException: Failure to transfer org.apache.cassandra:cassandra-all:jar:1.2.3 from h://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was 
             cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could 
             not transfer artifact org.apache.cassandra:cassandra-all:jar:1.2.3 from/to central (h://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): No response received after 60000
```

Can anyone suggest, what is need to add in POM.xml.

```
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.datastax.cassandra</groupId>
        <artifactId>cassandra-driver-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0-beta2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
        <artifactId>jetty-util</artifactId>
        <version>6.1H.5-beta</version>
    </dependency>            
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

Answer (score 1):

I have the similar error:

ArtifactTransferException: Failure to transfer commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.1.1 from http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced. Original 
 error: Could not transfer artifact commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.1.1 from/to central (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): No response received after 60000

I solved the problem by doing following steps:

1.Right click the project

2.Goto Maven

3.Click the "Update Project"

This solved my problem. Hope it will help you.